# How to develop windows phone app like logos quiz

Tags: c#, xaml, xna, logos

I'm developing a Windows Phone app that functions like the popular Logo Quiz in the App Store.

I know it involves a database to determine whether the answer is correct or not but I do not know how to put it to use, any tutorials are welcome :)

But the real problem is the popUp interface, there are some sample, some tutorials?

And.. better use XNA or XAML?

Thank you all!

Comment: before posting a question, please visit the faq : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask.

Comment: So, you want to make some random app that uses a database and a type of popup UI and you have no idea where to start? You probably aren't going to get many helpful responses because this question is extremely broad. Start by googling "Windows Phone Tutorial" and then ask questions as you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML is a good option.

As for samples or tutorials, try this from Nokia developer community..
This will give you a good starting point.

[How to create a Video/Audio/Image and Text based Quiz Game for Windows Phone](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_create_a_Video/Audio/Image_and_Text_based_Quiz_Game_for_Windows_Phone)